# Regular Expression to match zero or more spaces in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word, regex

I hope I'm just missing the obvious here, but how in the world do I match zero or more spaces with Microsoft Word 2010's "Regex" engine?

As a silly example, I want to match all of the following in a capture group:

```
cowseat grass
cows eat grass
cows  eat grass
cows   eat grass
cows    eat grass
```

I would normally do `(cows\s*eat grass)` and be done with it. But I can't see how to match zero or more spaces. I want to capture the whole phrase in a capture group, but I have variable number of spaces.

I've been using [this document](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/find-and-replace-text-by-using-regular-expressions-advanced-HA102350661.aspx) as a reference.

Comment: How is the expression `(cows\s*eat grass)` behaving? That should, as desired, match zero or more whitespace characters.

Comment: @KyleStrand Hi Kyle. The `\s` doesn't work for whitespace, so I used ` ` instead. The problem is I couldn't get `*` to work as "zero or more of the preceding character." I could use {1,}, but that doesn't handle when there are no spaces. Maybe I have a wrong setting in Microsoft Word? The Regex engine is very different from what I'm used to (PCRE).

Comment: yes, I can replicate the problem too. Can't make it match when there are no spaces

Comment: I don't have Word 2010, so I guess I'll just assume Microsoft fails at regex and call it a day. Sorry.

Comment: yes, according to this article http://word.mvps.org/faqs/general/usingwildcards.htm it looks like Microsoft in its infinite wisdom decided we don't need a 'zero or more' option

Comment: Ah, I see. Should have looked at the document you linked to before my first comment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The document you linked to shows that Microsoft's "regular expressions" aren't really regular expressions at all; they're a bizarre hybrid (bastard child, rather) of shell-style globbing (http://www.tldp.org/LDP/GNU-Linux-Tools-Summary/html/x11655.htm) and true regular expressions.

Since the glob syntax makes use of the `*` character as a synonym for the regex `.*`, and Microsoft decided (as mentioned in a comment) to make `@` equivalent to the regex quantifier `+` instead of `*` (which is stupid since `a+` is equivalent to `aa*` for any atom `a`, making `+` unnecessary), it looks like you're out of luck.

My personal opinion is that (1) this is stupid and (2) calling these patterns "regular expressions" is misleading at best, but unfortunately I don't see any way around this except for abandoning Word in favor of a tool that properly supports regex. (Though I suppose in theory you could try to parse the xml-ish format of the docx file itself, extract the text, and *then* apply your regex....)

Comment: So I just ran a "RegEx" without spaces and one with spaces. It introduced some silliness into the document, but I can fix those by hand. This is a huge gap in functionality in my opinion. Even more bizarre, Visual Studio has it's own Posix-y Regex's, but it's a lot more useble. They could have used that engine for Word. Ugh. Anyway, I'm gonna leave the question open for a few more days to see if anyone comes up with some clever workaround. Thanks Kyle.

Comment: @kmort - I am pretty sure it cannot be done. You can search for whitespace in "non-wildcard" mode using ^w, but then you cannot do grouping. Typically, this search would have to be done in VBA with multiple searches, or perhaps with VBA + VBScript's more powerful RegExp object (but then there are other undesirable consequences). Word's wildcard feature hasn't changed much since Word 6, around 1992 - I would guess it was based on one of the simple Posix regex standards of the time.